# DF showed 100% usage, reboot showed 8%

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

Just tried to login to phpMyAdmin on a DB server to be greeted with an error page due to insufficient space.

Logged in and sure enough was showing 100% usage, deleted a few large files (~5gb) but still showed 100% usage.

DU did not show anything helpful with few directories holding more than 1GB. Rebooted and usaged dropped down to just 8%.

Any ideas why this would happen? Running on a virtual machine using ESXi 6.7

```
root@ed:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              394M   41M  353M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  125G  124G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  197M  713M  22% /boot
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop3                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8790
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop6                          31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9279
secnaslg:/mnt/Z2/NFSBackup          11T  327G  9.8T   4% /mnt/backup
/dev/loop2                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17497
/dev/loop5                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17597
tmpfs                              394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0
root@ed:~# reboot
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20180318"
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64)

Last login: Fri Oct  9 11:47:11 2020 from 10.0.15.168
root@ed:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              394M  1.3M  393M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  125G  9.4G  109G   8% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  197M  713M  22% /boot
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop2                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17597
/dev/loop3                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17629
/dev/loop4                          31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9279
/dev/loop5                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8790
secnaslg:/mnt/Z2/NFSBackup          11T  327G  9.8T   4% /mnt/backup
tmpfs                              394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0
root@ed:~#
```

Comment: Are you using a swap file instead of a swap partition?

Comment: I am using swap file but set to 4GB

Comment: Did you, by chance, delete any large files (like logfiles or similar) in the time before the disk ran full ?

Comment: I also don't see /tmp in your mounts, that would reset on boot.

Comment: SorenA - Did delete some log files and some other old data files, deleting them did not make any difference and still showed 100% usage.

rtaft - did not check /tmp tbh, but did not see anything on a DU summary which added up, e.g. largest directory had only 4GB if it happens again will check /tmp first