# Disk usage reported as 100%, only 10% actually used

Tags: disk-usage

This is a followup to [DF showed 100% usage, reboot showed 8%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281385/df-showed-100-usage-reboot-showed-8)

System has been up just under a month and again is showing 100% disk usage on /

```
root@ed:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              394M   41M  353M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  125G  125G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  290M  619M  32% /boot
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
secnaslg:/mnt/Z2/NFSBackup          11T  357G  9.8T   4% /mnt/backup
/dev/loop6                          31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9607
/dev/loop3                          31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9721
/dev/loop7                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/17936
/dev/loop5                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/18013
/dev/loop2                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
tmpfs                              394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0
```

Temp directory only 904K, swap file only 4G. DU excluding /mnt (which contains mounted NFS share) shows only 12G total

```
root@ed:~# du -h --summarize /tmp/
904K    /tmp/
root@ed:~# du -h /swap.img
3.9G    /swap.img
root@ed:~# du -h --exclude=/mnt --summarize /
12G     /
```

After last time I did check a couple of times and disk space was going up slowly (from 8% to 9% after a week) machine is a VM running just a LAMP stack and a PHP bassed connector which connects to EDDN (data network for the game Elite Dangerous) to take feeds of market data and parse these into a MySQL DB.

Last time rebooting sorted (temporarily) showing 8% used after reboot. I am not in any rush to use machine at present so have left running in this state in hope someone can offer any ideas to check.

Not just a reporting issue, cannot write anything to disk.

```
root@ed:~# echo 1 > test
-bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

Comment: What is the output of `df -i /`?

Comment: `Filesystem                         Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 8323072 176986 8146086    3% /`

Comment: "*DU excluding /mnt shows only...*" -- Are you sure that your mounts are correct? Is it possible that you (or your software) had mistakenly saved files that are actually located under `/mnt`?

Comment: Mount definitely working, I did check as that has hit me on other servers :) plus this one doesn't actually write anything there yet.
Just to confirm, after unmounting...
`8.0K    /mnt/`

Comment: Check your cron backups -- just saw a "full root" problem which looked like the output device was not mounted, so the backup just filled up root.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past and it was caused for files stored in the mount point directories before the mount operation connected them to the corresponding partition/device.

To find out, reboot the system in recovery mode and launch a shell. Find the mount points of your system using `cat /etc/fstab` and looking in the second column of each uncommented line (the ones not starting with a # pound sign).

In recovery mode the root directory should be the only mounted partition, and read-only, but we are analyzing the system, so it doesn't matter, but if you have to make directories or edit files, remount it read-write using `mount -o remount,rw /` before doing that.

Check the actual space in use in the root filesystem with the command `du -x /`. This command ensures that `du` doesn't dive into other filesystems even if they were mounted. If the free space is low, then you have to find where it is used.

Next, use `du -x /directory` with each fstab mount point to check the space used in each directory. All should be empty, if not, you found the culprit. Check the contents looking if they are disposable and you could erase them, and if not, mount your backup partition to safely copy them there before the erasing.

If the mount point */mnt/backup* is the one filled, simply make another directory, say, */root/tmpbackup*, and mount the filesystem there temporarily. To avoid writing the full command for it, simply edit the */etc/fstab* file, copy the desired mount line to have a duplicate, comment one of them with # at start of the line and change the second column of the other from */mnt/backup* to */root/tmpbackup*. Save the file and mount it with `mount /root/tmpbackup`. This way you can restore the changes after finishing the fixing operations.

Now, if all mount points are empty (except the root, of course), then you have to find where all that space are used in the rest of the root filesystem. For this I recommend installing the *ncdu* program (`apt install ncdu`). To run it use: `ncdu -xq /directory` in the console or terminal. This command will read all filesizes below the /directory tree and show them sorted by directory sizes. Press h to check the help screen, enter to check inside a subdirectory or q to quit. I always install it in every new system just in case.

If you cannot install *ncdu*, simulate it (without the easy navigation) with *du*. For example, to check the sizes under /var use:

`du -csx /var/* | sort -nr | less`

where *-s* checks individual * arguments, *-c* shows total and *-x* restricts *du* to a single filesystem. As the results are numeric in bytes, we used *-nr* to sort them numerically and in reverse, and paged them with *less*.

Other posible culprits I have discovered sometimes could be a system or program log in */var/log* filling for a repetitive problem reported, or, if the system have full automatic updates, could be the downloaded/unpacked packages filling the remaining space, or some program/files we forgot to have stored somewhere in the system.

Good luck!

Note: Sorry for the sheer amount of text, but I prefer overexplaining terms for the future beginner users reading the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough points to comment. i'm going to take a risk and break the forum rules since this might help someone.

For me it seemed like a bug. check you inodes `df -ih` if you see a large percentage free on those volumes. the `tempfs` could have an incorrect reading and must be taking up all the space, if it was the same case as mine
, try this below -

Stop all your applications / services (like mysql/nginx/php/redis etc)

then

```
sudo rm -r /tmp/*
```

Or Just do a reboot, for my case i couldn’t reboot since my server was in prod.

[Incorrect Disk Usage Reporting on Ubuntu 22.04 Server clean install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458462/incorrect-disk-usage-reporting-on-ubuntu-22-04-server-clean-install/1458736#1458736)