# Incorrect Disk Usage Reporting on Ubuntu 22.04 Server clean install

Tags: disk-usage

In an ordinary scenario , full disks space means actually full disk space with a matter of hidden/small large files somewhere. just like this form states [RecoverLostDiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace)

I know my disk uses around `4GB` out of `sda` (50GB formatted) and 12GB on `sdb` (100GB formatted) but i get `No space left on device`

Previously -

I have a GCP VM with 2 drives, 1 with 30GB boot + an additional 100GB mounted.
main drive only has ubuntu 22.04 + mysql 8.0 installed. mysql disk is pointed to the mounted disk at `/mnt/disk/mysql_data`

when i `df -Th` it reports 100% (30GB availabile + 30GB used) used on `/`, when i use `du` and `ncdu` it reports that only 15GB (combined with mounted disk's data) has been used at `/` .

so i already found out that `df` can confuse the mounted drive as internal.

if so with that included i should have 50% free.
i tried many solutions and ended up resizing my drive from GCP to 50GB by taking a snapshot of the 30GB disk and creating a new 50GB disk with the previous image.

Before resizing

```
/dev/root      ext4    29G   29G     0 100% /
/dev/sdb       xfs    100G   12G   88G  12% /mnt/disks/data_disk
```

After resizing

```
/dev/root      ext4    49G   3G     0 16.3% /
/dev/sdb       xfs    100G   12G   88G  12% /mnt/disks/data_disk
```

Now the reading is suddenlycorrect ?? so case closed.

Now 2 weeks later im facing the same issue with 100% usage. the data on the mounted disk is still 12GB. when i try to create a file i get `No space left on device`

i cannot find where the missing space went??

i tried

- looking large files
- cleaning small files
- cleaning logs
- cleaning backups
- cleaning cache
- [suggested solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290027/1679951)

here is my `df -h` out put

```
df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root        6.2M  122K  6.1M    2% /
tmpfs            931K     1  931K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            800K   633  800K    1% /run
tmpfs            931K     4  931K    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda15          0     0     0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sdb          50M  8.8K   50M    1% /mnt/disks/data_disk
tmpfs            187K    20  187K    1% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Looks like there is `lvm` in use. Maybe an lvm-snapshot, which confuses the `df` ?

Comment: thanks, i didn’t even know `lvm` was. ill have to do some more research

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing, it seems to be a bug. `/temp` is read incorrectly.
before my solution, here is the `df -h` out put

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        49G   49G   17M 100% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.5G  692K  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      105M  5.3M  100M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb        100G   13G   88G  13% /mnt/disks/data_disk
tmpfs           745M     0  745M   0% /run/user/0
```

As you can see `tmpfs` uses less than 6GB, so i never borthered to clean it since its temp files which will get deleted automatically, plus cleaning 6GB didnt make sense that it would solve the reading error.

i just stopped mysql and ran the following,

```
sudo rm -r /tmp/*
```

now

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        49G  3.3G   46G   7% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.5G  692K  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      105M  5.3M  100M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb        100G   13G   88G  13% /mnt/disks/data_disk
tmpfs           745M     0  745M   0% /run/user/0
```

this explains why the storage showed free after the disk upgrade, because the `/tmp` gets wiped on reboot.

i'm closing this as question since its resolved using the following methods under the conclusion that its a calculation bug.

the version is

```
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

### Update

as [@Macro](https://askubuntu.com/users/549862/marco) mentioned, `/tmp` is a directory on the filesystem which is not necessarily the same as `tmpfs`, which is a filesystem. Previously i thought that `/tmp` is `tempfs`.

Comment: `/tmp` is not the same as `tmpfs`. It can be that `/tmp` is `tmpfs`, but it seems not in your case. Seems in your case `/tmp` is part of `/dev/root` and some process is filling it. You need to find out which process and fix it. Otherwise you need to reboot in short sequence.

Comment: yes, i found that mysql is responsible for this. i have already adjusted and fixed it. thanks.